# drawImage on instance in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, oop, html5-canvas, drawimage

I don't understand why the method drawImage doesn't work on the Canvas2D instance.

But when I put it in a setTimeout method it work, why?

```
function Canvas2D() {
  this._canvas = document.getElementById('screen');
  this._canvasContext = this._canvas.getContext('2d');
}

Canvas2D.prototype.clear = function() {
  this._canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, this._canvas.width, this._canvas.height);
};

let Canvas = new Canvas2D();

let image = new Image();
image.src = './assets/sprites/spr_background.png';

// Doesn't work here
Canvas._canvasContext.drawImage(image, 33, 71);

setTimeout(() => {
  // When I put it here it works
  // Canvas._canvasContext.drawImage(image, 33, 71);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: maybe the image is loaded by then ?

Comment: The reason is that the Image hasnt been completely loaded at the time you want to draw the Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image has to be loaded in order to be drawn correctly.
If you'd do something like:

```
image.onload = function(){
  Canvas._canvasContext.drawImage(image, 33, 71);
}
```

it should work, I guess...

After a 1 second timeout, it is likely that the image has been loaded within that time. The above code waits for the image to be loaded and then draws it. (so it can draw it earlier if it's been loaded within less than a second, and it won't fail if it takes more than a second)

Comment: Yes it works but then why it also works in setTimeout method?